# Constructing a Hamiltonian from a mass matrix?

Tags: mass, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

I was solving some questions regarding the Hamiltonian, which required a lot of algebra, but as I finished and looked professor answer I saw that he constructed a matrix from the kinetic energy and expressed the Hamiltonian in this way

$$H = \frac{1}{2}(m^{-1})^{jk}P_jP_k + V.$$

Could someone explain here why this is true? And why can you get Hamiltonian from a matrix related to how the mass is organized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This form of the kinetic energy is just a generalization of the usual
$$ H = \frac{P^2}{2m} $$
for the situation in which the speed in different directions contributes different amounts to the kinetic energy – a spherically asymmetric case. Note that the simple Hamiltonian above is equal to
$$ \sum_{i,j=1}^3 \frac{\delta_{ij}}{2m} P_i P_j $$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker symbol equal to one for $i=j$ and zero otherwise. Because of the definition of $\delta$ I just mentioned, the summation reduces to the summation over $i=j$, the $\delta_{ij}$ term may be dropped (it's one for $i=j$), and the index in $P_j$ is changed to $P_i$ so that we get $P_i P_i$, the usual square of the vector's length.

With the coefficient $\delta_{ij}/m$, we have the most general rotationally symmetric form of the Hamiltonian as long as the Hamiltonian is bilinear in $P_i$. We may replace this tensor $T_{ij} = \delta_{ij}/m$ by the most general symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix $U_{ij}$, which we may call $(m^{-1})_{ij}$, and that's how we get to your Ansatz.

There is really nothing to "derive" here. What you wrote down is a formula for the Hamiltonian in some systems that may be relevant for some objects – e.g. some electrons in certain crystals. Hamiltonians of different systems are given by various expressions – the detailed effective laws of physics in different contexts are different. So what I wrote above isn't a "derivation" – there can't be any derivation of this Hamiltonian that wouldn't assume anything equivalent. It's a "motivation" for why people sometimes use it.